# Filezilla ftp upload

Tags: ftp, upload

I'm in a very very strange situtation.

I use FileZilla for Windows 7, and when I upload  a file to my server I receive: "File transfer successful, transferred 14,939 bytes in 1 second", but when I go to my website to see the changes, nothing is changed.
When I try to upload the file again (overwrite it)  I noticed that the files have different sizes, like it was not uploaded.
I've tried this also on other servers and I have the same problem.

Comment: What is "your server"?  A webhosting company?  Something you run yourself?

Comment: No, I have a simple hosting for my website from a webhosting company

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you try it from a different client with other files?

Comment: Can you *add* files that weren't there before? Will they be available? Are you sure you're uploading into the correct directory? Make sure you don't use ASCII transfer mode, otherwise comparing file sizes makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to FileZilla. Sometimes same issue occurs to me, and then I use Windows File Explorer.
If you didn't know, you can use Windows File Explorer to access FTP, change file permissions, rename files, create directories... and much more as you would need to do with any other FTP Manager out there.
So how do you do it? Well, you can do it straightforward by copying the address like this:
ftp://your_ftp_username:your_ftp_password@your_ftp_host.com
and than pasting that address in the File Explorer address bar:[image: Windows File Explorer Address Bar]

After hitting enter you should be prompted with your FTP files and folders.
Now there is a second way, that is not better than the first one because if someone found out, they could delete all your data (only if you keep your computer unlocked and non-protected)
1. Create a shortcut
[image]

2. Point the shortcut to the target
   [image]
3. Name the shortcut
   [image]

   - There you have it :)
     [image]
4. Double-click it
   [image]